# CGMutablePath in Xamarin

Tags: swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to translate this code for my Xamarin.iOS app:

https://github.com/yourtion/YXWaveView/blob/master/YXWaveView/YXWaveView.swift

On line 179:

`let path = CGMutablePath()`

I can't find `CGMutablePath` in Xamarin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ObjC `CGMutablePathRef` struct (or Swift CGMutablePath class) is wrapped by `Xamarin.iOS` as a `CGPath` (`CoreGraphics` namespace).

```
var path = new CGPath();
```

#### xamarin-macios/src/CoreGraphics/CGPath.cs

```
public class CGPath : INativeObject, IDisposable {
        internal IntPtr handle;

        [DllImport (Constants.CoreGraphicsLibrary)]
        extern static /* CGMutablePathRef */ IntPtr CGPathCreateMutable ();

        public CGPath ()
        {
            handle = CGPathCreateMutable ();
        }

        [Mac(10,7)][iOS (5,0)]
        public CGPath (CGPath reference, CGAffineTransform transform)
        {
            if (reference == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException ("reference");
            handle = CGPathCreateMutableCopyByTransformingPath (reference.Handle, ref transform);
        }

        [DllImport (Constants.CoreGraphicsLibrary)]
        extern static /* CGMutablePathRef */ IntPtr CGPathCreateMutableCopy (/* CGPathRef */ IntPtr path);

        public CGPath (CGPath basePath)
        {
            if (basePath == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException ("basePath");
            handle = CGPathCreateMutableCopy (basePath.handle);
        }
 ~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
var path = new CGPath();
```